# show current clicked div hide previous clicked div

Tags: jquery

The code below is working, but with a problem I do not understand.
When I click on first navigation link it is showing the div, this is what I want,
but when I click on another nav link it does show the next div as expected
but I need for the previous div(s) to hide.
any help is appreciated.

something like: if this is not the nav link that was clicked hide. I would think.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('#navigation a').click(function (selected) {

    var getName = $(this).attr("id");
    var projectImages = $(this).attr("name");

    //console.log(getName);
    //console.log(projectImages);

    $(function() {     
      $("#" + projectImages ).show("normal");
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try adding a class to the div you are showing, and then hiding elements with that class when you show the new div(s).  Something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 

  $('#navigation a').click(function (selected) { 

    var getName = $(this).attr("id"); 
    var projectImages = $(this).attr("name");

    $(function() {      
      $(".current").hide().removeClass("current");
      $("#" + projectImages ).show("normal").addClass("current");
    }); 
  }); 
});
```

Comment: Definitely cleaner than my answer. The funny thing is that this is what I've done in several plugins I've written. :P

Comment: That worked as I need and expected.
thank you.  rosscj2533

ussteele

Comment: If you take this approach, be sure to remove the "current" class after you hide it.

Answer (score 0):

I would generally achieve this functionality by assigning a class to a `<div>` that wraps all of the images that need to be hidden. Then, upon every click, hide the appropriate div and show what you need:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#navigation a').click(function (selected) {

    var getName = $(this).attr("id");
    var projectImages = $(this).attr("name");

    $('div.special_images').hide();
    $("#" + projectImages ).show("normal");
  });
});
```

Also, you shouldn't need to wrap your projectImages show code with:

```
$(function() { ... });
```

It is a shortcut for the code you have above:

```
$(document).ready(function() {...});
```

which already wraps the entirety of your code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing at your markup:

```
<ul id='navigation'>
    <li><a href='#' id='nav1' name='nav1menu'>Link 1</a><ul id='nav1menu'>...</ul></li>
    <li><a href='#' id='nav2' name='nav2menu'>Link 2</a><ul id='nav2menu'>...</ul></li>
    <li><a href='#' id='nav3' name='nav3menu'>Link 3</a><ul id='nav3menu'>...</ul></li>
</ul>
```

Your question asks about the "last" click, but the end of the question seems to imply that all other menus should be closed. In that case:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('#navigation a').click(function (selected) {

    var getName = $(this).attr("id");
    var projectImages = $(this).attr("name");

    //console.log(getName);
    //console.log(projectImages);

    $(function() {
      $('#navigation ul').hide();
      $("#" + projectImages ).show("normal");
    });
  });
});
```

Notice that we hide all ULs before we click.

Hope that helps,
Joe

Comment: I think you mean `$('#navigation li').hide()`. `#navigation` is the `ul`.

Comment: Sorry, my <a> elements weren't very well formatted. The UL is nested, so that "#navigation ul" will target only those second-level ULs (which by convention are usually the submenus themselves). This way, we've trigger the submenu to show when we click, and to hide when we click something else.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing these divs aren't part of the navigation. Keep track of the last one opened and hide it before showing the next.

```
var = previousProjectImage = "";

$(document).ready(function(){

  $('#navigation a').click(function (selected) {

    var getName = $(this).attr("id");
    var projectImages = $(this).attr("name");

    //console.log(getName);
    //console.log(projectImages);

    $(function() {
      if(previousProjectImage != "") {
        $("#" + previousProjectImage).hide();
      }    
      $("#" + projectImages ).show("normal");
      previousProjectImage = projectImages;
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If the elements you're hiding/showing are siblings inside any element, this will work:

```
$(function(){
  $('#navigation a').click(function () {
    $("#" + $(this).attr("name")).siblings().hide().end().show("normal");
  });
});
```