# How can I show div on click, hide the others with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'd like to have a text area on my page that shows a div and hides the others (let's say 8 other divs). On click, I'd like the chosen div to show and the current div & other divs to hide. Is there a simple solution to this? Possible to build off of: [show current clicked div hide previous clicked div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2509807/show-current-clicked-div-hide-previous-clicked-div) ?

Comment: Something I left out - I would like these divs to show/hide when a different area of the page is clicked (li a).

Comment: I used `input` buttons in my solution to toggle the `divs`, is that what you meant?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a simple solution making use of chaining together methods.

```
$("input").click(function () 
{
    $("#" + $(this).attr("class")).show().siblings('div').hide();
});
```

[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/qNhZj/) ( *using $("input")* )
[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/5P9dB/) ( *using $(".className")* )

The activating buttons could have the same `class` as the `id` of the affected divs, or you can use a separate "toggler" class.

The important part is to use a unique feature of the clicked element to map to a unique feature of the toggled element.

Finally, if the toggling `divs` are not siblings, you can set up a selector of all of them using `var divs = $("#blah1, #blah2, #blah3, ...");` and toggle them using `.not()`.

[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/HVfaA/) of non sibling toggling `divs` using `.not()`

Comment: This worked fine - I used the .not() example and used img as my selector because my a.class was being used for another event. Thanks!

Comment: @ShawnB - Nice to hear. Don't forget to accept answers (the check mark below the votes) that solve your problems, and up vote answers you find useful.

Answer (score 2):

How about something like this?

```
$(document).ready( function(){
  $('div.some_class').click( function(){ // set of divs to be clickable
    $(this).siblings('div').hide(); // it's already showing, right?
  });
});
```

Of course, once one is clicked and the others are hidden, you'll have no way of bringing them back...

Answer (score 0):

it depends on the DOM structure. I'd personally give them some class to have an easy access to the whole group. `$('.div-group').hide(0, function(){$('#my-div').show();});`

Consider using jQuery UI Accordion, which might be an answer to functionality you need.