# jQuery show div on click, hide the others within multiple nested divs

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

When I place them inside of multiple divs, it does not seem to work any longer. What am I missing? Thanks

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/HVfaA/206/

```
<div id="content">
<div id="first">
<div id="first-1">
<div id="first-2">
<div id="first-3">
<li><a href="#" class="one">One</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="two">Two</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="three">Three</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="four">Four</a></li>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="second">
<div id="second-1">
<div id="second-2">
<div id="second-3">
<div id="one">One</div>
<div id="two">Two</div>
<div id="three">Three</div>
<div id="four">Four</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

$("div#second > div").hide();
var divs = $("#one, #two, #three, #four");
$('li a').on('click', function () {
$(divs).hide();
$("#" + $(this).attr("class")).show();
});​
```

This function is a modified version of the one offered by Peter Ajtai [jQuery show div on click, hide the others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3494975/jquery-show-div-on-click-hide-the-others)

Original question below:
I was trying use a separate divs containing the links and to show the divs.
Currently When the links are clicked, the hidden divs do not show. Thanks for your help.
Here's the demo on the jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/HVfaA/184/

```
<div id="first">
<li><a href="#" class="one">One</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="two">Two</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="three">Three</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="four">Four</a></li>
</div>
<br /><br />
<div id="second">
<div id="one">One</div>
<div id="two">Two</div>
<div id="three">Three</div>
<div id="four">Four</div><br/><br/>
</div>

// Optional code to hide all divs
$("div#second").hide();

// Selector
var divs = $("#one, #two, #three, #four");

// Show chosen div, and hide all others
$("li a").click(function () 
{
$("#" + $(this).attr("class")).show();
divs.not(("#" + $(this).attr("class"))).hide();
});
```

Comment: Omitting > div from $("div#second > div").hide(); to read $("div#second").hide(); seems to work on the nested div.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that you've wrapped all your divs in `div#second` and then hidden that element. Because their parent is hidden, none of the child divs (`#one, #two, #three, #four`) will show up.

If you'd like to hide all divs to begin with try

```
// Optional code to hide all divs
$("div#second > div").hide();
```

This isn't directly related, but as an aside you can leave off your `divs.not(("#" + $(this).attr("class"))).hide();` by just shifting the order of when you hide your divs (hide them all, then show the one). Also, since you already stored them as `divs` you can also just reference them directly.

```
// Show chosen div, and hide all others
$("li a").click(function () {
    $(divs).hide();
    $("#" + $(this).attr("class")).show();
});​
```

See updated Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/HVfaA/190/

Comment: The code inside of multiple divs does not work. Do you have a suggestions for this? Thanks

Comment: With the nested divs, I omitted the > div from the $("div#second > div").hide(); to read $("div#second").hide(); and it seemed to work fine from deep in the nested div. I had not idea the > div would cause it to not work. Thanks again Alex and all of the guys.

Answer (score 2):

Just show your div in your click handler and it will work:

```
$("div#second").show();
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/HVfaA/191/

Comment: user1479606, thanks so much for you assistance. I also appreciate the demo.

Comment: When nested inside of multiple divs, it does not seem to work. Can you take a look at the last few lines of codes?

Answer (score 0):

CSS:

```
.Main-Div {position: relative; left: -9999px;}
.Inner-Div {position: relative; left: 9999px;}
```

Javascript:

```
// Optional code to hide all divs
$("div#second > div").addClass('Main-Div');

// Selector
var divs = $("#one, #two, #three, #four");

// Show chosen div, and hide all others
$('li a').on('click', function () {
    $(divs).removeClass('Inner-Div');
    $("#" + $(this).attr("class")).addClass('Inner-Div');
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HVfaA/208/)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I was able to find the Alex version work in the nested divs once I removed the > div from this $("div#second > div").hide();